# Creating vector from two vectors in Julia

Tags: julia

I have two vectors, say, `x=[1;1]` and `y=[2;2]`

I want to construct a vector whose element is a combination of these two, i.e. `z=[[1,2],[1,2]]`

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`zip`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/collections/#Base.zip). By default, this will create a vector of tuples:

```
julia> z = collect(zip(x,y))
2-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1,2)
 (1,2)
```

Note that this is different than what you wanted, but it'll be much more efficient.  If you really want an array of arrays, you can use a comprehension:

```
julia> [[a,b] for (a,b) in zip(x,y)]
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1,2]
 [1,2]
```

Comment: For a far quicker method to get an array of arrays, use `collect(map(collect, zip(x,y)))`. While it is still slower than `zip` on its own, it is *significantly* faster than the comprehension. (My testing shows 500x!)

Comment: Not typically. You might be running into https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15276.